# How to create a HighCharts chart in react

Tags: highcharts, reactjs

How can I create a component with a HighCharts chart, that create the chart ones on the first render and only update the series data when new data comes in using `chart.series[0].setData(data,true);`

Comment: Use [react-highcharts](https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts) or at least you can base on the source code of that module.

Comment: Thats my problem, the component has no way to update the chart, it just rerender it on every update.

Comment: Then edit [componentDidUpdate](https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts/blob/master/src/Highcharts.jsx#L28) - compare previous options (arguments) with new state. If data changes - create new method to call `setData()`. If something else changed, call `renderChart()` again.

Comment: @PawełFus Is there a TypeScript type definitions-file available?

Comment: Definitions of what? Wrapper above? Or Highcharts? There are plans for type-defs for Highcharts, not ETA at this moment. I don't know anything about the wrapper above.

Comment: I was thinking about typedefs for react-highcharts.

Answer (score 3):

I have made a library called React JSX Highcharts, which might be what you're looking for. [GitHub](https://github.com/whawker/react-jsx-highcharts) / [NPM](http://npmjs.com/package/react-jsx-highcharts)

It allows you to create Highcharts charts with React components. So to update the series data, would just need to pass an updated `data` prop.

Behind the scenes, React JSX Highcharts would call `setData` for you.

### Example

```
<HighchartsChart plotOptions={plotOptions}>
  <Chart />

  <Title>My Highcharts Chart</Title>

  <Legend layout="vertical" align="right" verticalAlign="middle" />

  <XAxis>
    <XAxis.Title>Time</XAxis.Title>
  </XAxis>

  <YAxis id="number">
    <YAxis.Title>My Axis Title</YAxis.Title>
    <LineSeries id="series1" data={data1} />
    <LineSeries id="series2" data={data2} />
  </YAxis>
</HighchartsChart>
```

Comment: Is there a TypeScript type definitions-file available?

Answer (score 1):

As stated, you can use [react-highcharts](https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts). It provides an example of how to update the chart on it's readme page:

```es6
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    let chart = this.refs.chart.getChart();
    chart.series.addPoint({x: 10, y: 12});
  }

  render() {
      return <Highcharts config={config} ref="chart"></Highcharts>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getInitialState(){
        return({
            config:{
                /* HighchartsConfig */
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
                },
                series: [{
                    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 295.6, 454.4]
                }]
            },
        })
    },

componentDidMount(){
        let self = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            self.setState({
                config:{
                    /* HighchartsConfig */
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May']
                    },
                    series: [{
                        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0]
                    }]
                },
            })
            // chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'],true)
            // chart.series.addPoint({x: 10, y: 12});
            // chart.series.setData([29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0],true)
        },3000)
    },

<ReactHighcharts config = {self.state.config} ref="chart"/>
```

just like this,it works for me.