# How to integrate charts with react js component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React js in my project and we have some charts we need to display , I am using highcharts as my charting library. I am new to React so if anyone can help out with an example .

Comment: Could you post what you have tried? There are lots of examples online already: https://react.rocks/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not provided any info related to what exactly you want . You can start by looking through this stackoverflow post : [How to create a HighCharts chart in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30974404/how-to-create-a-highcharts-chart-in-react)

Then highcharts.com itself has a tutorial for http://www.highcharts.com/blog/192-use-highcharts-to-create-charts-in-react

https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts