# Importing JSON data file into graph

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm fairly new to React.

I am trying to import this following test json data file into my React graph.

```
{
    "data": [
        {"datetime": "", "data": [1,2,3,4]},
        {"datetime": "", "data": [1,2,3,4]}
    ]
}
```

The x-axis is the time so it should not matter very much. 
But I don't know how to read the data into the y-axis.

This is my Graph.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
import {
  HighchartsChart, Chart, withHighcharts, XAxis, YAxis, Title, Legend, LineSeries
} from 'react-jsx-highcharts';
import './Graph.css'
var jsonData = import '../jsonData.json'     //pass the json file location


class Graph extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.addDataPoint = this.addDataPoint.bind(this);

    const now = Date.now();
    this.state = {
        data: []
    }
  }


  componentDidMount() {

    //THIS is to add points from json


    //Please don't mind the stuff here--------
    //This is for another graph 
    var sensorSerial = this.props.match.params.sensorId
    const socket = socketIOClient("http://localhost:5001/test");
    socket.on("newnumber", data => this.addDataPoint(data));
    //----------------------------------------
  }


  addDataPoint(data){

    //This is for another graph------------
    if(data.sensorSerial == this.props.match.params.sensorId){
      var newData = this.state.data.slice(0)
      console.log(new Date(data.dateTime.split(' ').join('T')))
      newData.push([new Date(data.dateTime.split(' ').join('T')), data.number])

      this.setState({
        data: newData
      })
    }
    //-------------------------------------


  }



  render() {
    // const {data} = this.state;

    const plotOptions = {
      series: {
        pointStart: new Date("2019-04-04T10:55:08.841287Z")
      }
    }

    return (
      <div className="graph">
        <HighchartsChart plotOptions={plotOptions}>
          <Chart />

          //Title
          <Title>Sensor Data</Title>

          //Legend          
          <Legend layout="vertical" align="right" verticalAlign="middle" >
            <Legend.Title>Legend</Legend.Title>
          </Legend>

          <XAxis type="datetime">
            <XAxis.Title>Time</XAxis.Title>
          </XAxis>

          <YAxis>
            <YAxis.Title>Y-axis</YAxis.Title>
            <LineSeries name="Channel 1" data={this.state.data}/>
          </YAxis>

        </HighchartsChart>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withHighcharts(Graph, Highcharts);
```

If this is a duplicate question, please let met know!
I'm not a frequent on Stakoverflow, so if there's anything I can do to improve my post, please let me know.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: If you are using highcharts and react consider react-highcharts library. See this question about using it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30974404/how-to-create-a-highcharts-chart-in-react

Comment: Thank you! 
Also, if I want to change to a different graph using dropdown box, do I need another Graph.js just for the second graph?

Comment: Have a look at the github repo, (https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react#basic-usage-example) ; I believe you'd just have to change the constructorType prop in the ReactHighCharts component  for different types of chart to be displayed ,  and add the data used for that chart to the options object series value for your chart type. So you'd have your chart type as in state perhaps (state = {chartType: 'ganttChart'} ) and then when you select from you're dropdown , use the onChange event handler of the dropdown to update the state chartType .

Comment: Thank you! 
I have been thinking: should I just make SidePanel and Graph the same file? 

Maybe I can link them easier. 

I make the side panel and the graph 2 different files and I don't know how to call the graph from Graph.js to the dropdown menu in SidePanel.js